# Why is MySQL so slow for me?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a cloud server (GoGrid) with a x.x.x.x IP.
In this server I have an IIS installed and also a MySQL Server Community Edition.

In this server I have a website which connects to the database.
In my connection string, the I have put:

```
Server:localhost
```

Then I executed 400 inserts;
I took around 1 seconds or less.

Then I change the connection string to

```
Server:x.x.x.x
```

Then It took around 40 seconds to execute.
Why It is soo slow when I change the localhost to the own Machine IP?

I teste PING from x.x.x.x to x.x.x.x and I only took 1ms.

The server connection is about 10mb.

The data I'm inserting is not very large. Its about 10 columns only with date, id, label, and other simple types.

Also am using entity framework 6 with asp net mvc 5.

I'm missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: What kind of data are you inserting? It may not be MySQL that is slow, but the network connection to the server; remember that ping is not the only measure of network performance, throughput can be of even more importance.

Comment: Edited for clarity. The server connection is about 10mbit. The registry is simple, about 10 coluns with just labels and some ints and date.

Comment: If you are inserting 400 rows one at a time, there only needs to be an additional 1/10 second added to the "send data & receive confirmation" exchange to push it over 40 seconds. If you are looking for a better solution, as opposed to just wondering about the reason; have you tried inserting multiple values in one statement, or using Prepared queries?

Comment: In my case, I concatened the 400 inserts into one string, separeted with ';' then called the execute. There is a better way?

Comment: You don't need to repeat the INSERT portion over and over, after VALUES you can list sets like this `VALUES ([value_list]), ([another_value_list]), ([etc]);` Just watch out for queries that are too long. Though if you concatenated the queries into one message, the 1/10 second theory is probably eliminated; I can't say for sure as most my dev work has been on connections configured to only allow a single query per "execute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the connection string to the public IP address of your cloud server, you are likely forcing the traffic to your database from the local network adapter, to the cloud provider's internal network out to the public internet, back to the internal network, back to the local adapter that the request originated from.

Specifically, I know this happens with AWS, though with AWS I believe their assigned public DNS name is smarter about routing.

It is far more expensive to route the connection over the public internet than directly to MySQL on the local box.

Comment: The server is not from Amazon (edited). Its GoGrid. What is most intriguing is the huge difference in time. It tooke 39 more seconds to proccess.

Comment: Probably the same issue.  If you specify a public IP, it may be routed as described.  Is there a particular reason you want to specify the public IP?

Comment: Note that you might incur data usage charges if the database routes through the public IP.  Not sure what GoGrid's billing structure is like.

Comment: I was testing this way, because I'm thinking about changing from GoGrid to Amazon. And most important, separate my db server from my application server. In Amazon I would pick an EC2 Server for the app plus a RDS for the database. But now i'm afraid of this difference in performance.

Comment: If you use RDS, you will connect to that database using the Amazon internal network.  Performance from your instance to RDS is very good.  If in doubt open up a free account and try it out.

Comment: I tested a connection from EC2 to RDS and its wonderful. Works like localhost. I can migrate with safety as it looks like. Thank you.